# EKS Docker Image Pull CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, amazon-eks, mlflow

I'm trying to deploy a Docker image from ECR to my EKS. When attempting to deploy my docker image to a pod, I get the following events from a CrashLoopBackOff:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age               From                                   Message
  ----     ------                  ----              ----                                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled               62s               default-scheduler                      Successfully assigned default/mlflow-tracking-server to <EC2 IP>.internal
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  60s               attachdetach-controller                AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "<PVC>"
  Normal   Pulling                 56s               kubelet, <IP>.ec2.internal             Pulling image "<ECR Image UI>"
  Normal   Pulled                  56s               kubelet, <IP>.ec2.internal             Successfully pulled image "<ECR Image UI>"
  Normal   Created                 7s (x4 over 56s)  kubelet, <IP>.ec2.internal             Created container mlflow-tracking-server
  Normal   Pulled                  7s (x3 over 54s)  kubelet, <IP>.ec2.internal             Container image "<ECR Image UI>" already present on machine
  Normal   Started                 6s (x4 over 56s)  kubelet, <IP>.ec2.internal             Started container mlflow-tracking-server
  Warning  BackOff                 4s (x5 over 52s)  kubelet, <IP>.ec2.internal             Back-off restarting failed container
```

I don't understand why it keeps looping like this and failing. Would anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: The process inside the container is exiting; perhaps `kubectl logs` on the pod will say more.  Can you `docker run` the same image locally, without it exiting?  ("Exiting successfully" is "exiting" and will cause `CrashLoopBackOff`.)

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Looks like I was having issues connecting to postgres backend I intend to use on my mlflow kubernetes deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CrashLoopBackError` can be related to these possible reasons:

- the application inside your pod is not starting due to an error;
- the image your pod is based on is not present in the registry, or the
  node where your pod has been scheduled cannot pull from the registry;
- some parameters of the pod has not been configured correctly.

In your case it seems an application error, inside the container.
Try to view the logs with:

```
kubectl logs <your_pod> -n <namespace>
```

For more info on how to troubleshoot this kind of error refer to:

https://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.com/2020/05/troubleshooting-kubernetes.html

Answer (score 0):

The process inside container is crashing. Could be reason of entrypoint on docker base images.

You can try something like this to check the logs of container

```
kubectl logs -f <pod_name>
```